# Resolving Promise Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I use **ReactJS** and **axios** I try to GET data customer

React: **16.5.2** 
axios: **0.18.0**

I have a class with constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    reactTable: reactTableData(),
    reactBootstrapTable: reactBootstrapTableData(),
    dataCustomer: customerData(),
};
```

method **customerData()** :

```
export function customerData(){
  // axios get  
  return axios.get("my/url")
  .then(res => {
    let data = res.data.data;
    console.log(data);
    return data
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

when I am `console.log(this.state);` I got **Promise** data like this:

[image]

I still new with ReactJS and I hope you can help me, 
thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Either `await customerData()` or use Promises if you want an actual array. However, that would lead to the constructor being asynchronous which is usually a bad practice. You may want to leave the promises in and let the object interact with them as Promises.

Comment: state change won't be reflected on the component, Try to do ths api call in component lifecycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much normal, because you return a promise from your `customerData` function. I'd solve your problem like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    reactTable: reactTableData(),
    reactBootstrapTable: reactBootstrapTableData(),
    dataCustomer: [],
  }
  this.initCustomerData()
}

async initCustomerData() {
  this.setState({
    customerData: await customerData()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your customerData will return the Promise only which needs to be resolved. That promise is getting set in `dataCustomer`.

What you can do is, call the method `customerData` inside another method which can be triggered from `constructor` or any other lifecycle method. Resolve the promise and then call the `setState` method to set the desired value.

Answer (score -1):

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    reactTable: reactTableData(),
    reactBootstrapTable: reactBootstrapTableData(),
  };

  this.initCustomerData();
}

initCustomerData = () => {
  customerData().then((data) => {
   this.setState({ dataCustomer: data })
  });
}
```

Comment: This is almost same as Ruslan's answer, but does not require ES2017 support.

Comment: agree, i posted it 2 seconds after Ruslan's answer :) , but i saw that customerData use `then` and thought that the author use older version